# Magento 2 CityId does not have corresponding setter?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shipping, addtocart, quote

I have created an customer address attribute city_id while i am trying to add this attribute in the below following REST APis Getting bellow error.

> Property "CityId" does not have corresponding setter in class
>   "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface"**

```
POST /V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods
POST /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/estimate-shipping-methods
```

How can we solve? please help me.

thanks

[image]

Comment: i also get same error when place order logged customer but guest customer working fine i use below module https://github.com/vincent2090311/magento2-address

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 default, **does not has any field** `city_id` .IT has field **`city`**.

May be in your **system,you have create customer attribute**  `city_id`.

As per as magento2, system if you want  **create any custom attribute then** they suggest to use [**extension attribute**](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html) concept.

Follow this link as suggestion
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Comment: thanks @amit bera i already created city_id customer address attribute

Comment: hi @amit bera i have tried the above concept but not working can you please provide me the what exact steps need to follow ? as well as i have followed https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/   but no luck

Comment: i will check and get back to you when i will avaliable